# Seg Fault when accessing an array initialised with malloc

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, malloc

Below is a simplified extract of a program I'm writing. I'm having issues accessing elements towards the end of the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int n, char *args[n]){

    // create 4D array scores[10000][100][100][100] on heap

    uint64_t arraySize = 1;     // this avoids overflow
    arraySize *= 10000;
    arraySize *= 100;
    arraySize *= 100;
    arraySize *= 100;

    int (*scores)[10000][100][100] = malloc(arraySize);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            printf("%d, %d, %d\n", i, j, scores[i][j][0][0]);
      }
    }
  }
```

The program loops through the 4D array *score* and as a test I'm printing the contents of the array. The loop starts off as planned, printing in the format "*i*, *j*, 0" for each *i* and *j*, until the last success "25, 0, 0".
From this point on I get random numbers rather than 0, starting with "25, 1, 1078528" up until "25, 45, 1241744152" which is then followed by "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

After fiddling around I found the first non-zero array member to be *scores[25][0][7][64]*.

So I guess I'm running out of space and so am accessing memory I shouldn't be? If anyone knows or has an idea as to how I could fix this I'd really appreciate it.

My PC is running Ubuntu 16.10 64bit, has 16GB RAM and 16GB swap

**Edit**

After implementing the following suggestions I get a return value of *"calloc: Cannot allocate memory"*.

```
int (*scores)[100][100][100] = calloc(arraySize, sizeof(int));

if (scores == NULL) {
  perror("calloc");
  return 1;
}
```

If I comment out the new if statement (and run the for loop) I get an immediate seg fault. This also happens if I use malloc:

```
int (*scores)[100][100][100] = malloc(arraySize * sizeof(int));
```

Why could this be? Surely my system has enough memory
Cheers

Comment: You aren't initializing the array elements. Why do you expect them to be 0?

Comment: What ever your doing... your probably better off using [linked lists.](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html)

Answer (score 3):

- Check the return value of `malloc()` and determine if it failed to allocate.
- You forgot to multiply the size of `int`.
- The type of `result` should be `int (*)[100][100][100]`, not  `int (*)[10000][100][100]`.
- Using value of buffer allocated via `malloc()` and not initialized invokes *undefined behavior*, so don't do that.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int n, char *args[n]){

    // create 4D array scores[10000][100][100][100] on heap

    uint64_t arraySize = 1;     // this avoids overflow
    arraySize *= 10000;
    arraySize *= 100;
    arraySize *= 100;
    arraySize *= 100;

    int (*scores)[100][100][100] = calloc(arraySize, sizeof(int));

    if (scores == NULL) {
      perror("calloc");
      return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            printf("%d, %d, %d\n", i, j, scores[i][j][0][0]);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: note that `calloc(10000, sizeof *scores)` can be used (in accordance with the usual alloc idiom), no need for `arraySize`

Comment: Thanks! I ran your code and got the error "calloc: Cannot allocate memory". Sort of as expected but I would have thought that 16gb is plenty..

Answer (score 1):

Your pointer to a variable length array does not use correct array sizes.

The array is: `[10000][100][100][100]`

but the pointer is: `[100][10000][100][100]`

And you need to multiply the array size times the size of the object, in this case size of type int.

The pointer definition should be:

```
int (*scores)[100][100][100] = malloc(arraySize*sizeof(int));
```

The allocated elements are not initialized. Reading them will yield indeterminate values.

---

The correct type to store the size of bytes that need to be allocated, is size_t, not uint64_t.

One of the correct ways to allocate the array is:

```
const size_t bytes = sizeof( int[10000][100][100][100] );
int (*scores)[100][100][100] = malloc( bytes );
```

(This of course assumes that size_t can represent that value.)